# calcutate membership duration, until now or until end date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a MySQL table with (among others) the following columns:

```
[name] [member_since_date] [member_until_date]
```

When somebody's membership ends, the `[member_until_date]` field is populated, otherwise it contains NULL.

I need a purely SQL based solution for the following:

I want to calculate how long someone is a member: when `[member_until_date]` is filled, I need it to calculate `[member_until_date] - [member_since_date]`.

When somebody is still a member, the field `[member_until_date]` is `NULL`, so then I need it to calculate `[NOW] - [member_since_date]`.

I hope I'm clear enough on this, and I hope somebody has an answer for me.

Comment: I didn't had a clue how to start, so what have I tried? not very much... :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the difference between dates, in days, use DATEDIFF(). To take one value based on a condition, or another, use IF, though in this case I am using the similar IFNULL().

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(IFNULL(member_until_date, NOW()), member_since_date) AS days_member
FROM ...
```

IFNULL() says use the first argument, unless it's null, then use the second argument.

DATEDIFF() expects the larger date first in order to get a positive result.

COALESCE() provides similar functionality to IFNULL() and would be the ANSI SQL way of doing this.

Comment: thanks a lot! the IFNULL function is new to me, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

```
SELECT name, DATEDIFF(IF(member_until_date,member_until_date,NOW()),
   member_since_date) AS membership_duration
FROM members;
```

First, we check if `member_until_date` is null. If it is, we use `NOW()`, otherwise we use `member_until_date`.

```
IF(member_until_date,member_until_date,NOW())
```

Now we calculate the date difference between the above and the beginning of the membership, `member_since_date`, and return is as `membership_duration`.

```
DATEDIFF(IF(member_until_date,member_until_date,NOW()),
   member_since_date) AS membership_duration
```